# Calling a user defined function as callback parameter in fadeOut()

Tags: jquery, fadeout

A very basic question:

```
$(element).fadeOut("slow",myFunction());
```

This doesn't work. What is the correct way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
$(element).fadeOut("slow", myFunction);
```

Your code, i.e. adding `()` would actually run the code rather than defining it as callback.

Just some quick console playing:

```
function test() {}

typeof test // "function"
typeof test() // "undefined"
```

So the argument needs to be a function and not what a function returns (except that would be function, too).

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
$(element).fadeOut("slow", function(){
   myFunction();
});
```